# Create a countdown dialog menu box for a linux terminal?

Tags: linux, console-application

How do I make a dialog widget for the Linux Console (not X, but the "terminal" console) that would show a countdown in seconds next to a widget that might be a menu list or a textbox?

Ideally this might be a standalone program, like dialog, that is supplied parameters to control its behaviour.

When the countdown reaches 0, the selected value of the widget is returned. There could be a default value in case no human is present (or the human prefers the default).  The boot loaders like grub and lilo can do this already, pretty much.  I looked through the dialog man page and couldn't find this feature set.

Tried so far:

`dialog --timeout 30 --menu 'Menu Title' 20 60 3 'A' 'Choose A' 'B' 'Choose B' 'C' 'Choose C'` is close, but it doesn't show the 30 second timer ticking down.

`dialog --pause 'Hurry!' 10 60 30 --` shows a message and ok/cancel with the timer running but is only interstitial and not for user input.

It is possible to combine multiple lines like this:

```
dialog --menu 'Menu Title' 10 60 3 'A' 'Choose A' 'B' 'Choose B' 'C' 'Choose C' --pause 'Hurry up' 10 60 30
```

but that shows the widgets sequentially instead of combined on one page. Here, after the menu is answered with no timer, you get a message with a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for responding. To code it, I'd agree.  I was hoping someone had done it already.

Answer (score 3):

To stick to using dialog I have solved a similar problem by splitting this into two dialog boxes.  First a dialog box appears with the default value (and optionally alternative choices) displayed to the screen, and this has a countdown timer.  The user can hit esc or press cancel to change the option, or the countdown reaches 0 and the program continues with the default settings.  If the user hits escape then an second dialog appears which allows editing of the options.  I didn't want to add further software to our deb-live / clonezilla custom OS build and so I had to find a way with dialog.

```
dialog --title Some options to choose from, showing default --pause "\n\n Do you accept these options?:  \n  ${options_in_nice_format_for_display}" 20 60 5
[ $? -ne 0 ] && EDIT_IP=true || EDIT_IP=false

if ${EDIT_IP}; then
    dialog --editbox ${MY_OPTIONS_FILE} 20 60 2> ${EDITED_OPTIONS_FILE}
fi
```

For an even better solution (Which I have used but didn't want to add superfluous code here) you can add a while loop conditioned on the Boolean and allow repetitions of the edits until the user is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the `dialog` man page. Oh, you already did, you say? Then what’s wrong with:

> --pause text height width seconds
>
> A  pause  box  displays  a meter along the bottom of the box.  The meter indicates how many seconds remain until the end of the pause.  The pause exits when timeout is reached or the user presses the OK button (status OK) or the user  presses  the  CANCEL button or Esc key.

Comment: Thanks for pointing bringing my attention to this.  However, pause is a widget that displays a message, a countdown, and OK/Cancel. It is not an attribute or modifier to other widgets. So it won't implement a menu with a countdown.  --timeout 30 will add a 30sec timeout to a menu but there is no indication of progress.